# calculating unstandardised betas for categorical predictors

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am trying to calculate the unstandardised beta for a categorical variable in a linear regression model

y ~ c + βx1

where y (on the original scale) has a mean of 1000ms and a standard deviation 80 ms.

x1 is categorical and takes on two values as 0 or 1.

The **standardised** beta is 0.14

Is there a way i can derive the beta on the original scale? Is there a formula i would use?

I can find several references to the formula for transforming betas for continuous covariates but not for categorical ones.

Thank you

Comment: As an example of how to search our site to find answers, try this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=convert%20standardized%20beta%20&searchOn=3